# error code trying to copy a file with shutil in python

Tags: python

I'm a valorant player and I wanted to create a very basic Python script that is going to switch accounts for me (because you have to  actually start the game so you can do so).

Unfortunately the script returns an error that I can't understand and that's why I'm asking you to help me.

here is the code:
[image]

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile

account = input("enter account >>>")

def accountlog(account):
    file_nameaccount = r"C:/Users/lcc_zarkos/AppData/Local/Riot Games/Riot Client/Data/RiotClientPrivateSettings_",account
    file_name = r"C:/Users/lcc_zarkos/AppData/Local/Riot Games/Riot Client/Data/RiotClientPrivateSettings"
    copyfile(file_nameaccount,file_name)

accountlog(account)
os.system(r"C:/Riot Games/Riot Client/RiotClientServices.exe")
```

the output is in the image

Basically the launcher stores a file called RiotClientPrivateSettings (that I deleted but I am sure that's not why the script is not working) [image] that stores account data and for each account there is another file.
the python script is going to replace the RiotClientPrivateSettings file by the other account one which is going to make me login on the other account.

Comment: `file_nameaccount` is a pair. You concatenate strings with `+`, not with `,`.

Comment: oh tried with + but it leads to another error (updated the post)

Comment: Well, you left out the suffix parts of the file names...

Comment: im still learning python so can i ask you what do you mean ?

Comment: You need to add the .yaml extension as well in your code

Comment: http://prntscr.com/10czjdq
this means 'C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start' is not recognized as an internal or external command
, an executable program or a batch file.